execute a script on different remote machines on multiple files
I want to execute a script which is located on different machines. On each machine there is a set of files which the script should scan. I have something like this but it does not work:
for host in machine{11..14}; do ssh -q user@$host; 
    for i in $(ls -1 ~/current/nohup_node_?.out_202407*); 
    do   ~/bin/duration.sh $i; 
    done; 
done

the command just logins but doesn't find the file:
ls: cannot access '../nohup_node_?.out_202407??_??': No such file or directory



I suggest to replace for i in $(ls ...) with for i in ~/.... 2) The error doesn't really match the path given in the script. If you log onto one of these machines, does the ls work? 3) It might be worth looking into ansible.


there is no problem with the ls. I used this on one particular file only and it worked fine:

This command worked fine:
for host in machine{11..14};do ssh -q user@${host} "printf '%-15s' $host; ~/bin/duration.sh ~/current/nohup_node_?.out";done

You are using different paths everywhere: ~/current/nohup_node_?.out_202407*, ../nohup_node_?.out_202407??_?? or ~/current/nohup_node_?.out. So what is it now?

it is only one path for the files ~/current/

$(ls -1 ~/current/nohup_node_?.out_202407*) gives you the full path

Are you expecting the inner for loop to run on the remote machine?
